# not able to access apache 2 server running in vagrant from the host

Tags: ansible, apache2, ansible-playbook, vagrant

I'm running apache2 inside the vagrant guest machine .

Below is my vagrant file-

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/lunar64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
   end
   
   config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
   end
end
```

my playbook `provisioning/playbook.yml` is below -

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: make sure we can connect
      ping:

    - name: update the apt cache
      apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600

    - name: ensure apache2 is installed and up to date
      apt: name=apache2 state=latest

    - name: write the apache config file
      copy: src=templates/apache2/000-default.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      notify:
        - restart apache2

    - name: apache is running (and enable it at boot)
      service: name=apache2 state=started enabled=yes

  handlers:
    - name: restart apache2
      service: name=apache2 state=restarted
```

here is the `provisioning/templates/apache2/000-default.conf` -

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The commands `vagrant up` and `vagrant provision` are running fine.
When I login into vagrant guest os with `vagrant ssh` and do `curl http://0.0.0.0` is is working fine

[image: vagrant guest OS screenshot]

But when try to access from host OS with guest machine IP it is failing -

[image: host error]

How can I access the service correctly inside vagrant machine?

Comment: I guess the firewall is enable on host OS or this is a network communication issue. Are you able to ping to guest OS from host OS?